# Failed to run asp.net application using Selenium WebDriver in IIS

Tags: asp.net, selenium, iis, selenium-webdriver

I have an application developed in asp.net and I use the Selenium WebDriver library. when squeegee my own program in visual studio it raises the express iis server and opens my selenium application correctly, but when I put in iis server outside of visual studio development he comes to open my asp.net page, but when I run the code selenium to create a Iwebdriver:

```
IWebDriver Web = new InternetExplorerDriver();
Web.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");
```

it does not open me a web page and does not return error.

Answer (score 0):

I am unfamiliar with that particular library. But I'm reasonably confident that it's launching Internet Explorer *on the server* because web sites can't just arbitrarily launch programs on your computer without browser-specific plugins. If you were to examine the running processes on the server with task manager or a similar program, you should see the `iexplore.exe` processes when IE is started.

The reason it worked on your dev PC with IIS Express is that your client and server were on the same machine, and the server was running under your own user process.

Comment: is there any way to run the program this way I need?

Comment: @DiegoAugusto Not really an easy way. You'd need to RDP or VNC or use some other remote control to connect to the server to see IE running there. Or you could run IE on the local computer, and have a separate program on the local computer that communicates back up to the server.